# Read the docs autodoc works on Master but not Latest build

Tags: python, github, read-the-docs, autodoc

I am experiencing some strange build behaviour for my project on Read The Docs. When building the "Master" version the autodoc is generating the documentation properly. However, if I build "Latest" version then the autodoc generated documentation is blank. Both builds say they pass and expanding the different sections, I can't see any errors that suggest an issue. I'm baffled, they are both building from the same master branch of my github repo. Are there RTD settings that might be set differently for Master and Latest that might explain this behaviour?

My Github repo is here: https://github.com/MikeSmithLabTeam/particletracker

My Master and Latest rtd are:

https://particle-tracker.readthedocs.io/en/master/
https://particle-tracker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

the pages being built with autodocs are under the reference section at the bottom of the page.
"Preprocessing", "Tracking", "Postprocessing", "Annotation Methods"

If I look at the "Active Versions" page on RTD then Latest has Master in a slightly greyed font next to it which I presume means this is building from the master version (Is this the Master Branch of my github repo or does it mean its the "same" as my master version on RTD?).

Any suggestions on what might be causing this and how to start debugging it?

thanks

Comment: Your `latest` version on Read the Docs points to a particular branch on your repository. This is configurable. Take a look at the documentation at https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/versions.html

Right now, it seems that you have disabled `latest` branch and the link you pasted is 404ing